# Signal vector assignment in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have these signals in architecture:

```
signal sign1: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (21 downto 0); 
signal sign2: STD_LOGIC;
```

Then in some process I have this assignment. What does it mean? What value will be in sign2? 21th bit of the vector?

```
sign2 <= sign1(21);
```

Comment: VHDL also has so-called attributes, so you can do `sign2 <= sign1(sign1'left)`, which is easier to read and maintain than hard-coded magic numbers.

Comment: The right hand expression of the signal assignment is an indexed name which denotes and element of the array ( `sign1`).  The base type of the element type of the array type std_logic_vector is the same as the base type of std_logic allowing assignment to target `sign2`.  The numerical literal `21` denotes a *universal integer* value that is converted to type integer, the base type of the index type of std_logic_vector and is an index that specifies an element of the array.  It's an error if the index value does not fall within the index range of `sign1`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You're assigning the leftmost bit of sign1 to sign2.

Comment: That's it? You can't even describe the right hand expression as an indexed named?  What does it mean?